# Spatial Statistics (for mathematicians) lecture notes request

Tags: references, spatial

I'm currently doing a master's in mathematics, and I'm interested in spatial statistics, mainly for a project. Unfortunately, it seems impossible to find lecture notes on this topic. I have seen some books like Cressie's, but they are a bit overwhelming for an introductory purpose.

What I aim to know is the basic concepts, and the most basic estimators that we can derive. Can someone please point me out to some material that can be helpful?

Comment: Do you have a specific end project? I like Lesage and Pace's Intro to Spatial Econometrics, but that is mostly focused on spatial auto-regressive models for lattice data. If you had an end goal of kriging or point patterns that recommendation would not work (for point patterns I would recommend reading the R package spatstats documentation).